# Generic code does slow fibonacci while specific code is fast?

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, fibonacci

This code for computing the 40'th Fibonacci number just seems to hang.  It appears to be computing it the slow recursive way.

```
fibs :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
fibs = 0 : zipWith (+) fibs (1 : fibs)

main = do
    print (fibs !! 40 :: Integer)
```

On the other hand, if I change the type of fibs to

```
fibs :: [Integer]
```

Then it computes it immediately.

Why does changing the type to make it more specific effectively change the algorithm used to compute it? Is this a bug in GHC or is there something fundamental here?

Comment: I don't know *why* the two programs behave differently, but for me they behave the same when compiling with optimizations enabled (i.e. pass `-O` to ghc). The runtime difference is only visible when compiling without optimizations.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the poor performance is caused by your choice of type for `fibs`: it's too general for the compiler to perform fancy optimizations. Restrict it to  `[Int]` or `[Integers]`.

Comment: Oh right.  I forgot to compile with optimizations.  Still, even without optimizations I don't see why there should be a big-O difference.

Comment: Note that fibs is polymorphic. Without -O2 the fibs list is not being saved between calls so each element of fibs requires an exponential number of evaluations. With -O2 ghc identifies a specific instance (monomorphic version) of fibs and sets up a "global variable" to hold that specific instance.